# SQL - Finding Orders with only specific items

Tags: mysql, sql, combinations, calculation

I would like to find out the orders which contain one or more than one product: A, B, C.

the expected result is:

```
order_id
101              (explanation: product A, B, C)
103              (explanation: product A)
106              (explanation: product A, B)
107              (explanation: product B)
```

Orders

| id | deleted_at |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | null |
| 102 | null |
| 103 | null |
| 104 | null |
| 105 | 5-5-2021 |
| 106 | null |
| 107 | null |

Order_items

| id | order_id | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | A |
| 2 | 101 | A |
| 3 | 101 | B |
| 4 | 101 | C |
| 5 | 102 | A |
| 6 | 102 | D |
| 7 | 103 | A |
| 8 | 104 | D |
| 9 | 105 | D |
| 10 | 105 | B |
| 11 | 106 | A |
| 12 | 106 | B |
| 13 | 107 | B |
| 14 | 107 | B |
| 15 | 107 | B |

I've tried to write the code like this but it still contains other irrelevant orders.

```
select Orders.id
from Orders left join Order_items on Orders.id=Order_items.order_id
where Orders.deleted_at is null
group by Orders.id
having count(distinct(case 
when Order_items.product=A then 1
when Order_items.product=B then 1
when Order_items.product=C then 1 end)) between 1 and 3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the products that are not A, B, or C and be sure none of them are in the order:

```
select o.id
from Orders o join
     Order_items oi
     on o.id = oi.order_id
where o.deleted_at is null
group by o.id
having sum( oi.product not in ('A', 'B', 'C') ) = 0;
```

Note that this uses MySQL's convenient shorthand for counting boolean matches.

Comment: Thank you! it works!!!! But I have a further question about this.
How can I present it by products?
The expected result is 
product      sales
A                 3
B                 3
C                 1

Comment: @uyeahu . . . That is not the question you asked here.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if they exist, no joins required.

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    orders o
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            order_items oi
        WHERE
            oi.order_id = o.id
            AND oi.product IN (
                'A',
                'B',
                'C'
            )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! it works!!!! But I have a further question about this.
How can I present it by products?
The expected result is 
product      sales
A                 3
B                 3
C                 1

Comment: Could you please edit your question showing your expected output and how it differs from your original question? Not really clear on the new requirements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67923825/sql-finding-orders-with-only-specific-items-and-show-it-by-product?noredirect=1#comment120056536_67923825