# SQL - Finding Orders with only specific items and show it by product

Tags: mysql, sql, combinations, calculation

0

I would like to find out the orders which contain one or more than one product: A, B, C and show it by product.

I found that order #101, #103, #106 and #107 are the orders which contain product A or B or C only. But I want to show it by product

the expected result is:

```
product    qty
A          3      (explanation: order #101, #103, #106)
B          3      (explanation: order #101, #106, #107)
C          1      (explanation: order #101)
```

Orders

| id | deleted_at |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | null |
| 102 | null |
| 103 | null |
| 104 | null |
| 105 | 5-5-2021 |
| 106 | null |
| 107 | null |

Order_items

| id | order_id | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | A |
| 2 | 101 | A |
| 3 | 101 | B |
| 4 | 101 | C |
| 5 | 102 | A |
| 6 | 102 | D |
| 7 | 103 | A |
| 8 | 104 | D |
| 9 | 105 | D |
| 10 | 105 | B |
| 11 | 106 | A |
| 12 | 106 | B |
| 13 | 107 | B |
| 14 | 107 | B |
| 15 | 107 | B |

I've tried to write the code like this but it is still showing the product individually as I identify these orders by grouping the order id

```
select Order_items.product
from Orders join Order_items on Orders.id = Order_items.order_id
where Orders.deleted_at is null
group by Orders.id, Order_items.product
having sum( Order_items.product not in ('A', 'B', 'C') ) = 0;
```

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Fix your `group by`.  It should only have `orders.id`.

Comment: But it will group by `orders.id` but i would like to group it by products

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

Create a query that will make the orders distinct.

You can then use the distinct query results as a reference to count the quantity of the products. Since you're only trying to query the qty of the orders per product, you can use the amount of instances a product is present in the inner query as a reference.

```
select st.product, count(st.product) as qty from
(
select order_id, product from Order_items
group by order_id, product
) as st
group by st.product
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! but the qty is not correct at all as it follows the order_id to calculate the product qty and turned out to be 1 product for 1 order_id